# .htaccess mod_rewrite for web service as well as hide other files

Tags: linux, web-services, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I think I know how to hide the files but how do I use mod_rewrite to allow only the web service to be called in the same directory?

Here is the directory/file structure

```
/var/www/html/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.server.php
/var/www/html/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.client.php
/var/www/html/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.class.php
/var/www/html/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.ini
/var/www/html/xmlrpc/logs
```

Important note: /var/www/html/xmlrpc/logs has 777 permission 
before you start harping on me I plan to move this into a non public directory and give the correct permissions. But I was asked to see if I could hide it with the .htaccess file.

.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My hidden files"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/xmlrpc/.pswds
Require valid-user
```

.pswds

```
user:5/abcde1abcdE
```

Also I'm a newbie with mod_rewite/mod_alias and need this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.server.php
```

to be this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/xmlrpc/v1/
```

How does one do this?

Also on know on the virtual host setup in Apache you can set the log file paths/names, can this be done from the .htaccess file as well?

Examples are welcome as this is a learning experience for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah mod_rewrite.  Try this in the xmlrpc directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v1/$ xmlrpc.server.php [L]
```

Some questions though - does xmlrpc.server.php take any get parameters?  Can you guarantee that the url will always include a trailing slash?

To enforce a trailing slash as well as some other stuff, try this:

```
# Allows direct linking to files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Checks if the url is missing a slash, if so, evaluate rule below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

The last rule will have to be adjusted depending on where you put the .htaccess file.  If it's at the root, then it will work for all lower directories.  If it's in the xmlrpc folder, then you can leave off the localhost.

Also remember to restrict access to the .htaccess file:

```
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Someone else will have to answer the other questions - not as familiar with that.

Comment: A couple of questions: the XMLRPC script does take parameters but only using the XMLRPC service not from the URL, does this matter? also I used local host as an example and the production URL is something like: http://site/xmlrpc/service/server.php I think I understand that how to make the changes for this. last note for restricting the .htaccess file, is this is the default sites available?

Comment: 1) I believe that the parameters should be okay.
2) The trailing slash check is easy to change - just swap out the localhost for whatever your production host is.
3) As for restricting the .htaccess, I'm not quite sure what your question is.  The example is a file restriction - blocks web browsers from opening up the .htaccess file.

Comment: it would be to hide the other files from the public but have the xmlrpc.server.php only accessible

Comment: The simplest way to do that would be to place the other files outside of webspace - leave only the xmlrpc.server.php file in public space.  If they absolutely must all be in the same system directory, you can get around this by putting them all outside of public space, then just using a symbolic link in the public folder.  (/home/user/public_html/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.server.php -> /home/user/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.server.php).  PHP includes go by system path, not url, so those should all work.